# The delete of my child entites failed if more than 1 element

Tags: entity-framework

I have an `Itinerary` which may contains 0, 1 or more `TransportInfos`.

```
public class Itinerary
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<TransportInfo> TransportInfos { get; set; }
}

public class TransportInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Itinerary Itinerary { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the following function to delete a bunch of itineraries and related `TransportInfos`.

```
    public void DeleteItineraries(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        var itinerariesToDelete = Context.Itineraries.Where(it => ids.Contains(it.Id)).Include(b => b.TransportInfos).ToList();

        itinerariesToDelete.ForEach(it =>
        {
            it.TransportInfos.ForEach(ti => Context.TransportInfos.Remove(ti));
            Context.Itineraries.Remove(it);
        });
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

- If I have only 1 `TransportInfo` inside my `Itinerary` then the delete succeed.
- If I have more than 1 `TransportInfo` inside my `Itinerary` then I got the error below:

**The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.**

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the following changes:

- Add ItineraryID to TransportInfo
- change List to ICollection

Comment: The `ItineraryID` was already present. I forgot to mention it here. You put me in the right direction by talking about the `List & ICollection`. Finally I got it working by performing my `Remove` like this: `it.TransportInfos.ToList().ForEach(ti => Context.TransportInfos.Remove(ti));`. Thank you.